# Instead of MySQL ORDER BY RAND

Tags: mysql, sql, random, sql-order-by

I use this query:

```
SELECT f.id FROM articles f
JOIN ( SELECT RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM articles) AS max_id ) AS m
WHERE f.id >= m.max_id
ORDER BY f.id ASC
LIMIT 5
```

The problem is that it returns an unexpected number of rows. It can be 1 row or 3 rows or 5 rows. But I need exactly 5 rows.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Select 5 random rows? Select 5 contiguous rows (ordered by id, starting at a random position)?

Comment: I wanna select 5 random rows

Answer (score 2):

A possible issue that your query has is that it only selects one record randomly and the rest of record are sequential. If you want to truly select all 5 randomly, you'll have to select them one by one:

```
(SELECT f.id FROM articles f INNER JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM articles) + 1) AS random) m ON m.random = f.id) UNION ALL
(SELECT f.id FROM articles f INNER JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM articles) + 1) AS random) m ON m.random = f.id) UNION ALL
(SELECT f.id FROM articles f INNER JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM articles) + 1) AS random) m ON m.random = f.id) UNION ALL
(SELECT f.id FROM articles f INNER JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM articles) + 1) AS random) m ON m.random = f.id) UNION ALL
(SELECT f.id FROM articles f INNER JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM articles) + 1) AS random) m ON m.random = f.id)
```

This works if the IDs are sequential with no gaps. If you have gaps, you'll have to change the equality to less than, and limit to one record:

```
(SELECT f.id FROM articles f INNER JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM articles) + 1) AS random) m ON m.random <= f.id LIMIT 1) UNION ALL
(SELECT f.id FROM articles f INNER JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM articles) + 1) AS random) m ON m.random <= f.id LIMIT 1) UNION ALL
(SELECT f.id FROM articles f INNER JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM articles) + 1) AS random) m ON m.random <= f.id LIMIT 1) UNION ALL
(SELECT f.id FROM articles f INNER JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM articles) + 1) AS random) m ON m.random <= f.id LIMIT 1) UNION ALL
(SELECT f.id FROM articles f INNER JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM articles) + 1) AS random) m ON m.random <= f.id LIMIT 1)
```

However, like dnswlt mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48956524/3215948). The classical solution, which is much simpler, will work for small tables:

```
SELECT f.id
FROM articles f
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Your five joins will return 0 or 1 row, most likely 0, exept if all five calls to `RAND` yield the same value :)

Comment: @dnswlt Of course. It needed unions between those subqueries. I have no idea how the query ended up like that. I guess I was tired, copy/pasted the inner subquery instead of the outer one and forgot to add unions. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 1):

Your question looks like a duplicate of [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast).

Depending on how many rows you have in your table and the response time you're willing to accept, you could try the classical variant first:

```
SELECT f.id FROM articles f
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

If it's less than a million, this might suffice.

Else you can apply the trick described in the linked article, and `UNION ALL` 5 such queries, roughly like so:

```
(SELECT r1.id
  FROM articles AS r1 JOIN
       (SELECT CEIL(RAND() *
                     (SELECT MAX(id)
                        FROM articles)) AS id)
        AS r2
 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
 ORDER BY r1.id ASC
 LIMIT 1)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT r1.id
  FROM articles AS r1 JOIN
       (SELECT CEIL(RAND() *
                     (SELECT MAX(id)
                        FROM articles)) AS id)
        AS r2
 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
 ORDER BY r1.id ASC
 LIMIT 1)
 UNION ALL
 ... (three more queries to retrieve 5 rows)
```

If you have few rows, there is some likelihood of duplicates in this solution. But if you have few rows, you can use the simpler solution above anyway :)

I created an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b42780/8) for the second variant. HTH!